# GRUB fails to load Windows in "dual-boot" with ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows-8, external-hdd

I've just installed Ubuntu from live DVD in my external HD to try it before using it in dual boot with windows 8. I deleted my Windows backup to make room for it so, even if I have the rescue disk I would get the factory system.

Situation:

if the external HD is connected on boot I get the correct GRUB which lets me choose OS, but windows can't load, it says "can't load image" in /EndEntire.

if it is not connected, I get a GRUB bash-like enviromment, but I don't know anything about it. (Minimal bash-like line editing is supported.)

What can I do to at least recover Windows 8?

thanks to the answer I found someone with exactly the same problem
Boot Info Script:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/MokManager.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38761 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT

/dev/sda1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda

GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     2,050,047     2,048,000 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda2       2,050,048     2,582,527       532,480 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3       2,582,528     2,844,671       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda4       2,844,672   591,591,423   588,746,752 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5     591,591,424   625,141,759    33,550,336 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1               2,046   231,190,527   231,188,482   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sdb5               2,048   231,190,527   231,188,480   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdb2         231,190,528   259,522,559    28,332,032  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3    *    259,522,560   976,772,559   717,250,000  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        1AF88187F881623D                       ntfs       WINRE_DRV
/dev/sda2        9883-4C19                              vfat       SYSTEM_DRV
/dev/sda4        0480864E808645E0                       ntfs       Windows8_OS
/dev/sda5        603AFDBB3AFD8DF2                       ntfs       Lenovo_Recovery
/dev/sdb2        5de69a97-717c-43d6-b090-8967eff2b1d2   swap       
/dev/sdb3        2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda2        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw)
/dev/sdb3        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sdb3/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd2,msdos3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos3  2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd2,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos3  2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-36-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-36-generic-advanced-2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos3  2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-36-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-36-generic-recovery-2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos3  2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos3  2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd2,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos3  2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-9883-4C19' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  9883-4C19
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9883-4C19
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sdb3/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc3 during installation
UUID=2226bf96-3170-4af5-8bf5-971ee2df340e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9883-4C19  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=5de69a97-717c-43d6-b090-8967eff2b1d2 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb3: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sdb

00000000  eb 06 00 00 00 00 00 00  33 c0 fa 8e d0 bc 00 7c  |........3......||
00000010  fb 8e d8 8b f4 8e c0 bf  26 7e 06 57 bf 00 7e b9  |........&~.W..~.|
00000020  00 02 fc f3 a4 cb be 02  7e ad 8b c8 66 ad bb 00  |........~...f...|
00000030  80 83 f9 00 75 2e be be  7f ac 3c 80 74 1b 83 c6  |....u.....<.t...|
00000040  0f 81 fe fe 7f 75 f2 be  44 7f e8 33 00 be 92 7f  |.....u..D..3....|
00000050  e8 2d 00 33 c0 cd 16 cd  19 83 c6 07 66 ad b9 01  |.-.3........f...|
00000060  00 bb 00 7c 32 f6 e8 24  00 be 62 7f 72 dc 8b f3  |...|2..$..b.r...|
00000070  81 c6 fe 01 ad be 7f 7f  3d 55 aa 75 cd 06 53 cb  |........=U.u..S.|
00000080  b4 0e fc ac 3c 00 74 04  cd 10 eb f7 c3 66 60 1e  |....<.t......f`.|
00000090  06 66 50 53 51 52 8b ec  b4 41 bb aa 55 8a 56 00  |.fPSQR...A..U.V.|
000000a0  cd 13 72 39 81 fb 55 aa  75 33 f6 c1 01 74 2e 66  |..r9..U.u3...t.f|
000000b0  33 c0 66 50 66 8b 46 06  66 50 8b 46 0a 50 8b 46  |3.fPf.F.fP.F.P.F|
000000c0  04 50 66 b8 10 00 01 00  66 50 16 1f 8b f4 8b 56  |.Pf.....fP.....V|
000000d0  00 b8 00 42 02 e6 cd 13  83 c4 10 eb 50 b4 08 8a  |...B........P...|
000000e0  56 00 33 ff 8e c7 cd 13  72 43 66 83 e1 3f fe c6  |V.3.....rCf..?..|
000000f0  8a de 66 8b 46 06 66 33  d2 66 f7 f1 42 52 8a cb  |..f.F.f3.f..BR..|
00000100  66 33 d2 66 f7 f1 8a f2  59 66 3d ff 03 00 00 77  |f3.f....Yf=....w|
00000110  1b 86 e0 c0 e0 06 03 c8  8e 46 0a 8b 5e 04 8b 46  |.........F..^..F|
00000120  00 8a d0 80 c4 02 b0 01  cd 13 eb 01 f9 5a 59 5b  |.............ZY[|
00000130  66 58 72 0b 81 c3 00 02  66 40 49 0f 85 52 ff 07  |fXr.....f@I..R..|
00000140  1f 66 61 c3 0d 0a 42 4f  4f 54 20 20 20 70 61 72  |.fa...BOOT   par|
00000150  74 69 74 69 6f 6e 20 6e  6f 74 20 66 6f 75 6e 64  |tition not found|
00000160  21 00 0d 0a 45 72 72 6f  72 20 6c 6f 61 64 69 6e  |!...Error loadin|
00000170  67 20 62 6f 6f 74 20 73  65 63 74 6f 72 21 00 0d  |g boot sector!..|
00000180  0a 42 61 64 20 62 6f 6f  74 20 73 65 63 74 6f 72  |.Bad boot sector|
00000190  21 00 0d 0a 50 72 65 73  73 20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65  |!...Press any ke|
000001a0  79 2e 2e 2e 0d 0a 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |y...............|
000001b0  65 6d 00 00 00 63 7b 9a  b0 36 70 1b 00 00 00 20  |em...c{..6p.... |
000001c0  1f 00 0f fe ff ff fe 07  00 00 02 a8 c7 0d 00 fe  |................|
000001d0  ff ff 82 fe ff ff 00 b0  c7 0d 00 50 b0 01 80 fe  |...........P....|
000001e0  ff ff 83 fe ff ff 00 00  78 0f d0 5d c0 2a 00 00  |........x..].*..|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 08 fe 1b  |.X.MSDOS5.0.....|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 48 1f 00  |........?....H..|
00000020  00 20 08 00 01 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |. ..............|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 01 29 19 4c 83 98 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..).L..NO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 44 69  |..............Di|
000001b0  73 6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72  ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73  |sk error...Press|
000001c0  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  20 74 6f 20 72 65 73 74  | any key to rest|
000001d0  61 72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |art.............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdc 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-LTwHcu4r/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off secure boot, and grub should be able to boot Windows (bug 1091464)

---

Another bug, 384633, has the initial grub.cfg file using the wrong devices (because the install media was counted, causing the sdc to be used instead of b etc.).  You may be able to fix this by first editing the grub commands (instructions at bottom of screen, changing the devices hd2 to hd1 etc and sdc to sdb.  After a successful Ubuntu boot, running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

should fix the problem permanently.

Comment: Right now I set boot priority to Windows Boot Manager, and Windows loaded, but of course I won't be able to open ubuntu. First of all I'll get a backup of windows, then I'll try disabling secure boot (I had no option to disable it in BIOS)

Comment: the bug you posted seemd like mine, but changing boot priority (to ubuntu again) made me encounter the same problem, even with SecureBoot disabled.
I think my mistake was setting the bootloader in 'dev\sdc\' so GRUB is not complete

I'm a newbie to linux so I really don't know if I'm wrong...
Do you think that I can "delete" GRUB to get the system exactly as it was before?